# jQuery: How to update row number when first row added?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a table like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>rowNumber</td>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>item1</td>
            <td>250000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>item2</td>
            <td>250000</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I also adding new row this way (data will be adding to table when new record added):

```
if ($('#table').length) {
     $('#table tr:first').after("<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + ? + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.Title + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.Price + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>");
}
```

As you can see, I add new row to the first row of the table. Now I want to add new row with rowNumber 1 then all other rowNumber get update.
Any idea?

Comment: Loop through and set the html of the cells with the new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have appended the new row, you can set the rowNumber going through all rows (except the first one):

```
if ($('#table').length) {
    $('#table tr:first').after("<tr>" +
        "<td></td>" +
        "<td>" + data.Title + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + data.Price + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");

    $("#table tr:not(:first-child) td:first-child").each(function(index,item){
        $(this).text(index+1);
    });
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcuk8q7s/2/)